# Scroll vertical collection view along with whole view

Tags: ios, swift

I have two collection views as seen on the image on the link. I want such that when I scroll the vertical collection view up, the other views together with the horizontal collection view on top of it should scroll together. How can I do this?

[The above image shows two collection views, the one on top is a horizontal collection view while the one on the bottom is a vertical collection view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G2agG.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like in the code snippet I just provided...

Implement the scroll view delegate method... and based on the collection view scrolled, set the content offset of the other one as per your calculations...

```
let horizontalCollectionView = UICollectionView()
let verticalCollectionView = UICollectionView()

func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    if scrollView == horizontalCollectionView {
        // set the content off set of the vertical collection view
    } else if scrollView == verticalCollectionView {
        // Set the content off set of horizontal collection view
    }
}
```